# Set default colModel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using JQGrid, is it possible to set a default colModel in order to prevent repetition of code?
For example instead of

```
colModel:
[
{name:'name',index:'name',width:80,align:center},
{name:'license',index:'license',width:80,align:center},
{name:'birthday',index:'birthday',width:80,align:center}
]
```

We could just set `width:80` and `align:center` to be default values and just do

```
colModel:
[
{name:'name',index:'name'},
{name:'license',index:'license'},
{name:'birthday',index:'birthday'}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's very possible. See this option of jQGrid: [**cmTemplate**](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

Basically, you can define any default properties you want your `colModel` to use.

For example, we will set each column's default width to `80` and the alignment to `center`:

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid({
    cmTemplate: {
        width: 80,
        align: 'center'
    },
    // the rest of your jqgrid setup here
});
```

Now in your `colModel`, every column will have a default width of `80` and will be `center` aligned. You can of course override the defaults you just setup if need be in a given column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge grid (which contains a thousands rows) then assigning **align: 'center'** in **cmTemplate** is not very optimal because of EVERY **td**-tag will contain **style**-attribute like this:

```
<td .. style="text-align: center" />
```

try to calculate overhead of markup size for 1000 rows -> 1000 * 26 byte ~ 25kb

I would prefer to use css-class:

```
.grid-centered-cells .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { text-align: center; }
```

which should be applied to container which cover grid

```
<div class="grid-centered-cells">
    <table id="grid"></table>
</div>
```